# Inverting Conditional Distributions

Tags: probability, statistics

I am doing a problem that in which I've been thinking for hours. I have $X$ that distributes as a Standard Normal and $Y/X$ that distributes as $\mathbb{U}[|x|-1/2,|x|+1/2]$ and I am asked to find the conditional density of $X/Y$.

I have been trying to find the marginal density of $Y$ using the joint density found by $f(Y/X)*f(x)$ but I have been super unsuccesful.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't usually furnish hints in the form of the answer itself, but for this question, it seems appropriate:

$$f_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y) = \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{2\sqrt{2\pi}} \begin{cases} \left(\Phi(y+\frac{1}{2}) - \Phi(y-\frac{1}{2})\right)^{-1}, & \bigl||x|-y\bigr| \le \frac{1}{2} \cap y > \frac{1}{2} \\ \left(\Phi(y+\frac{1}{2}) - \frac{1}{2}\right)^{-1}, & |x| \le y + \frac{1}{2} \cap y \le \frac{1}{2} \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}, \end{cases}$$ where $\Phi(x) = \Pr[X \le x]$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution.

Now that you can see the answer, this should hopefully give you a hint as to how to proceed:  you need to sketch the region of integration corresponding to the support of the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

An animation of the conditional density as $y$ ranges from $-1/2$ to $3$:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I've been trying to integrate over that V domain but I have a mess!

Comment: Just one question, what is what you have at the right of the key?

Comment: @JuanManuelCastro What do you mean, "at the right of the key?"  Please be specific.

Comment: You have that the conditional function is the standard normal divided by 2 and there is a key to its right

Comment: There is an additional factor that is a piecewise function of $x$ and $y$:  if $y > 1/2$ and $||x|-y| \le 1/2$, then you choose to **divide** by $\Phi(y+1/2)-Phi(y-1/2)$.  If $y \le 1/2$ and $|x| \le y + 1/2$, then you choose to divide by $e^{-x^2/2}/(2\sqrt{2\pi})$ by $\Phi(y+1/2) - 1/2$.  If $(x,y)$ is not in the v-shaped region, then the density is zero.  The first case corresponds to the portion of the v-shaped region where the support of the density over $x$ is discontinuous; the second case corresponds to the case where the support is continuous.

Comment: thank you you are Fisher resurrected!